# Error: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init() - Visual Studio Xamarin, unit test error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios

I made an android application in Visual Studio, using Xamarin. I have an emulator installed in visual studio. The applaction uses txt files, which I made on the emulator earlier (File.WriteAllText). The problem is that I can't run unit tests. DependencyService.Get throws an error.

```
Test 
Result Message: Unable to create instance of class (...). Error: System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it..
```

I'm not sure where I'm wrong, and what I should do here.

There's an IPersistence class which gives the loading from file method.

```
public interface IPersistence
    {
        Task<Player[,]> Load(int x);
    }
```

I implemented it for android in another class:

```
 public class AndroidDataAccess : IPersistence
 {
        public async Task<Player[,]> Load(int x)
        {
               /*...*/
        }
 }
```

Unit test Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Model;
using Persistence;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Test1
    {
        private Model _model;
        private IPersistence _dataAccess = DependencyService.Get<IPersistence>(); //It throws an error.
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {

            _model = new Model(_dataAccess);
            _model.GameWon += new EventHandler<GameWonEventArgs>(Model_GameWon);
            _model.GameOver += new EventHandler(Model_GameOver);
            _model.FieldChanged += new EventHandler<FieldChangedEventArgs>(Model_FieldChanged);
            _model.GuardChanged += new EventHandler<GuardChangedEventArgs>(Model_GuardChanged);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void BasicTest10()
        {
        _model.NewGame(10);
        Assert.AreEqual(4, _model.S);
        }
```

Comment: What are you testing? Show us your test.

Answer (score 1):

`DependencyService` requires a `Forms` context to operate. This is normally created when creating the `MainActivity` for Android or the `AppDelegate` for iOS. For your test I would recommend creating a test fixture for each platform and then create a method that manually initialises `dataAccess` based on the platform.

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
public class Test1 {
   ...
    ...
    private IPersistence InitialisePersistance(Platform platform) { ... }
}
```